# Get updated position of an element after click

Tags: jquery

After I click a button an element's left position is animated, I need to get that new position, not the starting position.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('div.move').animate({left: 300});
    var v = $('div.move').position().left;
    console.log(v); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/czQBm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value as a callback:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('div.move').animate({
        left: 300
    }, function () {
        var v = $('div.move').position().left;
        alert(v);
    });

});
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czQBm/1/)